# Existing Db, Invalid ColumnNames

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a SQL Server database running with EF6. Now I start a new project on this DB and would like to EF.Core.

During development I use a small 'handmade' TestDb with the same columns as my original ProductionDB.

After writing code for a few tables, I changed my connection string from TestDB to ProductionDb, the problem starts.

A simple `context.XXX.Count()` works, but running other queries where I get in touch with column names, I always get some errors

> Invalid column name xyc

In a very easy query I have four to five of them.

To be clear, these columns do exist in both databases they only differ in small properties (DateTimes(0) to DateTime20) or null/notnull.

Any idea where to look?

Thanks in advance
Peter

More information

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        LoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();
        loggerFactory.AddProvider(new TraceLoggerProvider());

        optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(loggerFactory)
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()

/*           
*           This is the TestDb
     .UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=XYC;
     Initial Catalog=Erp_Dach_Core;
     Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
*/
   // ProductionDb goes here

         .UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=XYC;
        Initial Catalog=Erp_Dach;
        Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
    }
}
```

This is the production DB with table `Employees`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employees] 
(
        [Id]               INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
        [EmployeeId]       NVARCHAR (10)    NOT NULL,
        [Id_old]           UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
        [Gender]           NVARCHAR (1)     NULL,
        [Salutation_Id]    INT              NOT NULL,
        [Firstname]        NVARCHAR (50)    NULL,
        [Lastname]         NVARCHAR (50)    NULL,
        [EmployeeShortCut] NVARCHAR (50)    NULL,
        [DateOfBirth]      DATETIME2 (7)    NOT NULL,
        [DateOfHire]       DATETIME2 (7)    NOT NULL,
        [LeaveDate]        DATETIME2 (7)    NULL,
        [VacationDays]     INT              NOT NULL,
        [CreatedAt]        DATETIME2 (7)    NOT NULL,
        [CreatedBy]        NVARCHAR (50)    NULL,
        [UpdatedAt]        DATETIME2 (7)    NULL,
        [UpdatedBy]        NVARCHAR (50)    NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Employees] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
        CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Employees_dbo.Salutations_Salutation_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Salutation_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Salutations] ([Id])
);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Salutation_Id]
ON [dbo].[Employees]([Salutation_Id] ASC);
```

'TestDb' goes here:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employees] 
(
        [Id]               INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
        [CreatedAt]        DATETIME2 (0)    NOT NULL,
        [CreatedBy]        NVARCHAR (50)    NULL,
        [UpdatedAt]        DATETIME2 (7)    NULL,
        [UpdatedBy]        NVARCHAR (50)    NULL,
        [Id_old]           UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
        [Employee_Id]      NVARCHAR (10)    NOT NULL,
        [Gender]           NVARCHAR (1)     NULL,
        [Salutation_Id]    INT              NOT NULL,
        [Firstname]        NVARCHAR (50)    NULL,
        [Lastname]         NVARCHAR (50)    NULL,
        [EmployeeShortCut] NVARCHAR (50)    NULL,
        [DateOfBirth]      DATETIME2 (0)    NOT NULL,
        [DateOfHire]       DATETIME2 (0)    NOT NULL,
        [LeaveDate]        DATETIME2 (7)    NULL,
        [VacationDays]     INT              NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK_Employees] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
        CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Employees_dbo.Salutations_Salutation_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Salutation_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Salutations] ([Id])
);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Employees_Salutation_Id]
ON [dbo].[Employees]([Salutation_Id] ASC);
```

Error:

> 'Ungültiger Spaltenname' = 'Invalid ColumnName'
>
> Nachricht:
>
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Ungültiger Spaltenname "Employee_Id".
>   Ungültiger Spaltenname "CreatedAt".
>   Ungültiger Spaltenname "CreatedBy".
>   Ungültiger Spaltenname "UpdatedAt".
>   Ungültiger Spaltenname "UpdatedBy".
>
> Stapelüberwachung:
>
> SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
>   SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>   TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>   SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
>   SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>   SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
>   SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
>   SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String method)
>       SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
>       SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>       SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>       DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
>       RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
>       Enumerator.InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result)
>       SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
>       Enumerator.MoveNext()
>       List`1.ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>       Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>       <b__0>d.MoveNext() Zeile 44
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>       EmployeeRepository.LookupAsync(Boolean onlyActive) Zeile 26
>       EmployeeFixture.ReadAllEmployees() Zeile 28
>       <>c.b__139_0(Object state)

Comment: *with the same Columns as my original ProductionDB* -- Well, `Employee_Id` isn't in the production table, so that's not true. Why don't you use an exactly identical test db? Also `null` or `not null` may cause differences in behavior.

Comment: Hi, i found the solution. There is an Employee_Id Column in a Join Table , And this Column produces the error. Thanks for the help. Peter